# Cannot access specific website (MBP - OS X 10.10.5)

Tags: macos, network, dns, websites

I’m having problems connecting to a certain website. It’s random whether the site loads but recently it’s been getting worse. What happens is that I turn my router and computer off at night, then after rebooting in the morning more often than not the site in question will not load. This happens even though I could access it the day before without any difficulty. A reboot of the router is what triggers the glitch. All other web sites load as they should.

The site itself is ok since I can access it via a proxy server and DownForEveryoneOrJustMe.com verifies it’s online. I suspect it has to do with my computer since I can access the site using an Android tablet via wifi (same router & modem).

Things I’ve tried on my computer:

- tried 3 different browsers (Firefox, Safari, Opera);
- cleared the browsers' caches and disabled firefox addons
- ran Onyx in automation mode, rebooted.
- deleted SystemConfiguration in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration then rebooted.
- tried booting into 2 different HD disks.
- flushed the DNS cache (from Admin account)
- added/removed DNS addresses on Google & OpenDNS. Currently use my ISP’s DNS addresses.
- disabled OS X firewall briefly. Disabled & reinstalled GUI app for OS X firewall.
- disabled LittleSnitch, rebooted.
- checked /etc/hosts (localhost entries only)
- changed MTU to 1453 in Preferences > Network > Advanced > Hardware (Manual, 1453)
- called my ISP. They told me it was a problem with my computer.
- A ping test results in 100% packet loss and Request Timeout.

Router & modem

- reset router and modem to factory settings and rebooted.
- tried 2 different routers; one wifi, one wired, same maker.
- bypassed the router so that the modem was connected directly to my computer. Problem persisted after modem/computer reboot.

I have no anti-virus software installed but I recently upgraded to a new modem. Am using a Macbook Pro on OS X10.10.5. I’d appreciate any suggestions as I’m out of ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what the website is? What happens if you don't reboot the router and only reboot the Mac? What happens if you don't reboot the Mac and only reboot the router? What happens if you boot the Mac in Safe Mode?

Comment: 1. rense.com 2. no change 3. sometimes site becomes available, but not always 4. In Safe Mode, site still down, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that it was a faulty LAN connection that was causing the problem so I replaced the LAN cable and connector. Not sure how doing this was related to a single(?) web site not loading but I no longer need to reboot the router (leaving it off for 10+ mins) and restart the browser. A second wireless router that I occasionally use also boots OK now, whereas before it was hit and miss.

**Update**: Still some infrequent issues so I reset the MTU value (System Prefs > Network > Advanced > Hardware) from automatic (1500) to 1460. Everything is now back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Run Disk Utility from the Utilities folder and "Repair Permissions."  Let it run.  It will take a while.  When it is done, quit the program.

2 - Reinstall an anti-virus program and run a scan.

3 - Open Safari and from the "Safari" menu, click on reset Safari.

4 - Go to System Preferences, click on "Security and Privacy."  Make sure your firewall is set to "ON."

Comment: Thanks, had tried Repairing Permissions but no effect, #3,4 it's not only in Safari but other browsers too. #2 may try AV later, although booting in Safe Mode had no effect.